# контент во всю длину и ширину экрана - автоматическая респонсивность

Tags: html, css, height

У меня вопрос - я начинающий фронт-энд девелопер. Пытаюсь построить сайт, контент которого умещается на видимой части страницы (любой высоты и ширины). Построила на ширину 1440 и высоту 1024. Есть ли какая-то другая возможность умещать весь контент автоматически на видимой части экрана, или без респонсивности (трудоемкий процесс в данном случае) этого невозможно добиться никак? Я сейчас не говорю про мобильные и планшеты. Я говорю о десктопный версиях.
И какая максимальная высота, под которую нужно подстраивать контент?
Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй bootstrap, очень удобно, подключаешь как обычный css файл, есть множество видео и статей, как это сделать. Все позиционируется автоматически, потому что ты используешь уже готовые стили, которые написаны для разных размеров экранов.
Вот ссылочка: https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/5.0/layout/containers/

Comment: Со стилями без проблем. Бутстрапом пользуюсь. Но на странице не только бутстраповские элементы - а свои отступы, высоты и другое. И все это нужно поголовно настраивать. Страница вся не подстроится под бутстрап. Но за ответ спасибо. Буду надеяться на дополнительные советы/ответы/рекомендации.

Comment: Как вариант задавать свои отступы, высоты и другое в процентах.